# Laravel Existing Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a database we use on some of our existing websites, sites were built in Yii framework by another developer so no Laravel, I have set up a new project using laravel but am looking for the best way to link up to that database and return the information.

linking to the database is easy enough, just change the database.php file but I am getting really confused with migrations part and how to call it into a webpage.

So what's the simplest way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Migrations are used to create or modify database structure. Since you already have a database set up, you don't need to use migrations.

To get accustomed with Laravel I strongly suggest watching:

> **[Laracasts -  Laravel 5 Fundamentals](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals)**

I also suggest you go over the entire [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0) just to get acquainted with all the framework has to offer.